# Recursively list files within folder and unpack zip ones

Tags: python, list, recursion, zip

I'm trying to recursively list all files inside a folder (including subfolders) and unpack the zip ones. Tha'ts how i'm doing:

```
def scan(real_path):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in walk(real_path):
        for filename in fil(filenames, '*'):
            matches.append(path.join(root, filename))
    return matches


def unzip(destination, path):
    z = ZipFile(path, mode = "r")
    for archive in z.namelist():
        content = z.read(archive)
        archive = open("%s/%s" % (destination, archive), "w")
        archive.write(content)
        z.close()


def startup_files(starting_over = False):
    print "STARTING FILES AGAIN..." if starting_over else \
          "STARTING FILES..."

    x = scan(folder)
    print "Files found in folder:"
    print x
    for archive in x:
        archive = Archive.details(archive)
        print "READING:", archive.full_path
        if archive.extension == ".ZIP":
            unpack_zip(archive)
            remove(archive.full_path)
            startup_files(True)
```

Which is causing this bizarre error. I'm testing the script with 2 files, `1.zip` and `2.ZIP`, in which file i have this file: `SFPDB001.GBK`

The output is:

Iteration one: ok

```
STARTING FILES...
Files found in folder:
['arp\\_input\\backups\\1.zip', 'arp\\_input\\backups\\2.ZIP']
READING: C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\1.zip
```

Iteration two: ok

```
STARTING FILES AGAIN...
Files found in folder:
['arp\\_input\\backups\\2.ZIP', 'arp\\_input\\backups\\SFPDB001.GBK']
READING: C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\2.ZIP
```

Iteration three: ERROR: The scan function is finding the right files inside the folder, but the iteration is trying to reach unavailable files.

```
STARTING FILES AGAIN...
Files found in folder:
['arp\\_input\\backups\\SFPDB001.GBK']
READING: C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\SFPDB001.GBK
READING: C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\SFPDB001.GBK
READING: C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\2.ZIP

C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\_input\backups\2.ZIP

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arp\__main__.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "arp\__main__.py", line 18, in main
    ARP(p.parse_args()).run()
  File "C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\arp.py", line 26, in run
    self.startup_files()
  File "C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\arp.py", line 46, in startup_files
    self.unpack_zip(archive)
  File "C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\arp.py", line 62, in unpack_zip
    Zip.unzip(self.folder, archive.full_path)
  File "C:\Users\G1745 IRON\Development\LL\ARP\arp\zip.py", line 17, in unzip
    z = ZipFile(path, mode = "r")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\zipfile.py", line 339, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\G1745 IRON\\Development\\LL\\ARP\\arp\\_input\\backups\\2.ZIP'
```

I don't have any idea why this is happening... i have a JS background, and i'm starting with python now, so i don't know if i should do something.

OBS: I'm using Python v2.5 because its a legacy code.

Comment: Well, the error doesn't leave us many possibilities... File `C:\\Users\\G1745 IRON\\Development\\LL\\ARP\\arp\\_input\\backups\\2.ZIP` doesn't seem to exist at all. Maybe it's misspelled?

Comment: By the way, the error is not in iteration 3 as you said... It's still in iteration 2.

Comment: The file exist when the program starts, but he is deleted in the second iteration. The second iteration is iterating over files that are not in the array of scanned files... really bizarre.

Comment: I found the error, i should return when i call the startup_files again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, i should return the `startup_files` when i call it from the looping:

```
return self.startup_files(True)
```

That's all.